# How to download all pages inside a category in Wikipedia?

Tags: mysql, mediawiki, wiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I would like to retrieve all the articles urls (I don't need the entire text) inside a Wikipedia Category.

For example, if I want to obtain all article urls from the following category: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:History , what is the best way to do that?

Is it necessary to download the entire mysql dump and make manual queries?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Wikipedia API.

The ["query"](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query) action, on the ["categorymembers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bcategorymembers) list, is what you want here. An example of a query to list pages in a category might be:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:History&cmprop=title

Note that:

1. By default, the results are returned as formatted HTML displaying JSON data. This is purely intended for debugging, not for production use. Pass the `format=json` parameter to get unformatted JSON back from the API. (There are a number of other formats available as well; read the documentation for details.)
2. The results of this query are paged. You can increase the page size using the `cmlimit` parameter, but ultimately you may need to page the results by extracting the `cmcontinue` value from the results and passing that in a parameter of the same name.
3. Many of the "pages" within the category are actually other categories. There is no way to recursively list the contents of a category and all categories it contains, as Wikipedia's categories are not a hierarchy. Some categories will contain categories that contain them, or which contain other categories which are not strict subsets. (Wikipedia's "categories" are really more tags than categories, but the name's old enough that there's no way of changing it now.)

Comment: I don't want to use the api, because I want to get subcategories pages too (recursively with depth 8 or more).

Comment: As I explained, don't do that. Wikipedia categories are not hierarchical; you will end up with a lot more articles than you expected, and many of them will be unrelated to the original category. Even if you do decide - against my advice - to recurse, the API will be the easiest way of doing that.

Comment: I understand, I think I will use https://petscan.wmflabs.org/ with depth <= 5 to avoid off topic articles.

Comment: These days continuation works by getting the key-value pairs in the `continue` property of the result set and adding them to the query.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using PHP to help with this, the [addwiki/mediawiki-api](http://addwiki.readthedocs.io/projects/mediawiki-api/en/latest/index.html) library has a system to recursively retrieve all pages in a given category. Something like the following:

```
$api = new \Mediawiki\Api\MediawikiApi( 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php' );
$services = new \Mediawiki\Api\MediawikiFactory( $api );
$categoryTraverser = $services->newCategoryTraverser();

// Get the root category.
$rootCatIdent = new PageIdentifier( new Title( 'Category:History' ) );
$rootCat = $this->factory->newPageGetter()->getFromPageIdentifier( $pageIdentifier );

// Get all page URLs:
$allPages = $categoryTraverser->descend( $rootCat );
foreach ($allPages->toArray() as $page) {
    echo 'https://en.wkipedia.org/wiki/'.$page->getPageIdentifier()->getTitle()->getText();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Doesn't have to be MySQL. There's easier ways.
You can just write a short code to do so. 
Just use regex or find the keyword like the link has a specific pattern to locate them :

```
in this case it's
"< a href="/wiki/ " or so as the starter
"</a>" to the end
```

Comment: whatever languages

Comment: But that would be like "crawling", that's what I want to avoid.

Comment: Trying to imitate a web crawler is almost always going to be the worst approach. APIs/dumps/etc are provided exactly so that you don't have to go through it.